# Extracting data from HTML to Java objects

Tags: java, html, message

I have a message log from a messaging application stored as HTML. In the file, a single message is presented in the following way:

```
<div class="message">
  <div class="message_header">
    <span class="user">User Name</span>
    <span class="meta">10 february 2018 at 16:17 UTC+01</span>
  </div>
  <p>Message content</p>
</div>
```

The messages are not nicely arranged in the file - there may be multiple messages per line and sometimes the lines end in the middle of a message.

I'd like to create an instance of class `Message` with fields like `userName`, `date` and `messageContent` for each item in the file. Is there any elegant way to do this?

I was planning to iterate over the file and split each line every time a new message starts and then get the data from the string but I'd rather avoid it if there's a less tedious way.

Comment: Use JSoup. It's a very good way to parse HTML, and it will even clean up the HTML for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us YOUR code.

Answer (score 2):

My answer won't probably be useful to the writer of this question (I am 5 months late so not the right timing I guess) but I think it will probably be useful for many other developers that might come across this answer.

Today, I just released (in the name of my company) an HTML to POJO complete framework that you can use to map HTML to any POJO class with simply some annotations. The library itself is quite handy and features many other things all the while being very pluggable. You can have a look to it right here : https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-htmltopojo

### How to use : Basics

Imagine we need to parse the following html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Simple HTML Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="restaurant">
            <h1>A la bonne Franquette</h1>
            <p>French cuisine restaurant for gourmet of fellow french people</p>
            <div class="location">
                <p>in <span>London</span></p>
            </div>
            <p>Restaurant n*18,190. Ranked 113 out of 1,550 restaurants</p>  
            <div class="meals">
                <div class="meal">
                    <p>Veal Cutlet</p>
                    <p rating-color="green">4.5/5 stars</p>
                    <p>Chef Mr. Frenchie</p>
                </div>

                <div class="meal">
                    <p>Ratatouille</p>
                    <p rating-color="orange">3.6/5 stars</p>
                    <p>Chef Mr. Frenchie and Mme. French-Cuisine</p>
                </div>

            </div> 
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's create the POJOs we want to map it to :

```
public class Restaurant {

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > h1")
    private String name;

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(2)")
    private String description;

    @Selector( value = "div.restaurant > div:nth-child(3) > p > span")    
    private String location;    

    @Selector( 
        value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(4)"
        format = "^Restaurant n\*([0-9,]+). Ranked ([0-9,]+) out of ([0-9,]+) restaurants$",
        indexForRegexPattern = 1,
        useDeserializer = true,
        deserializer = ReplacerDeserializer.class,
        preConvert = true,
        postConvert = false
    )
    // so that the number becomes a valid number as they are shown in this format : 18,190
    @ReplaceWith(value = ",", with = "")
    private Long id;

    @Selector( 
        value = "div.restaurant > p:nth-child(4)"
        format = "^Restaurant n\*([0-9,]+). Ranked ([0-9,]+) out of ([0-9,]+) restaurants$",
        // This time, we want the second regex group and not the first one anymore
        indexForRegexPattern = 2,
        useDeserializer = true,
        deserializer = ReplacerDeserializer.class,
        preConvert = true,
        postConvert = false
    )
    // so that the number becomes a valid number as they are shown in this format : 18,190
    @ReplaceWith(value = ",", with = "")
    private Integer rank;

    @Selector(value = ".meal")    
    private List<Meal> meals;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And now the `Meal` class as well :

```
public class Meal {

    @Selector(value = "p:nth-child(1)")
    private String name;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(2)",
        format = "^([0-9.]+)\/5 stars$",
        indexForRegexPattern = 1
    )
    private Float stars;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(2)",
        // rating-color custom attribute can be used as well
        attr = "rating-color"
    )
    private String ratingColor;

    @Selector(
        value = "p:nth-child(3)"
    )
    private String chefs;

    // getters and setters.
}
```

We provided some more explanations on the above code on our github page.

For the moment, let's see how to scrap this.

```
private static final String MY_HTML_FILE = "my-html-file.html";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    HtmlToPojoEngine htmlToPojoEngine = HtmlToPojoEngine.create();

    HtmlAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = htmlToPojoEngine.adapter(Restaurant.class);

    // If they were several restaurants in the same page, 
    // you would need to create a parent POJO containing
    // a list of Restaurants as shown with the meals here
    Restaurant restaurant = adapter.fromHtml(getHtmlBody());

    // That's it, do some magic now!

}


private static String getHtmlBody() throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(MY_HTML_FILE));
    return new String(encoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}
```

Another short example can be found [here](https://github.com/Louis-wht/jwht-htmltopojo-booking-example)

Hope this will help someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the HTML as an XML and use the dom package for java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html
or you can do unmarshaling with JAXB.